# Ionic 3 image uploading through camera as well as camera gallery

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have attached my ts file code. I am not able to send image to server .its seems working means I am getting notification that your image is successfully uploaded. But I am not able to see change. Please help - thanks

```
public presentActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        title: 'Select Image Source',
        buttons: [
                     { text: 'Load from Library',
                       handler: () => {
                             this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
                       }
                     },
                     { text: 'Use Camera',
                       handler: () => {
                            this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
                       }
                     },
                     { text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel' }
                 ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you provided is just to show the action sheet that selects between selecting the source between the library and the camera itself.  There is no code there for uploading it to the server.

I would expect something like this for an upload to firebase storage (my personal favorite)

```
uploadPic() {
let that=this
let imagefile = this.base64Image.split(',')[1] //this gets rid of the "data:image/jpeg;base64," part of the file

let uploadTask = firebase
  .storage()
  .ref(this.uid)
  .child("profile_pic")
  .putString(imagefile, "base64", { contentType: "image/jpg" });
uploadTask.on(
  firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function(snapshot:any) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
    console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log("Upload is paused");
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log("Upload is running");
        break;
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(error));
  },
  function() {
    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    console.log("got to downloadURL")
    that.downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
    that.updateAuthUser();
  }
);
```

}

You can find similar code in the firebase docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

The code above will be different if you use a different destination server that google firebase storage for your uploaded image.